# Script to check folder estructure

Tags: powershell, structure, directory

I'm trying to build a script that does a scan a folder tree and verify that they are with the correct name.

Basically, as an example, I have the following folder structure:

```
├───01
│ ├───010001
│ │ ├───010001102030405060
│ │ │ ├───declarante
│ │ │ ├───docs
│ │ │ ├───entidadelegal
│ │ │ ├───proprietario
│ │ │ └───representante
│ │ └───010001102030405061
│ └───010002
├───02
├───03
└───04
```

As this network folder, often the owners do not create folders in places due. Daily encounter situations such as:

```
├───01
│ ├───010001
│ │ ├───010001045715873654
│ │ ├───010001741014756984a
│ │ ├───010001741z14756984
│ │ ├───0144dshbc
│ │ └───014758
│ ├───010002
│ ├───010003
│ └───010004a
├───02
├───03
└───aaa
```

- In the first level of folders, there are only the folders 01, 02 ... 13.
- In the second level folders are folders in which the name only has 6 numbers, with the proviso that the 2/1 match the folder where the first level (eg Level 1: 01 folder, level 2: folder 010,001 ... level 1: 02 folder, level 2: 020,001 folder ...).
- In the third level folders are folders in which the name has only 18 numbers, provided that 6/1 correspond to the folder where the previous level (eg Level 2: 010001 folder, level 3: 010001102030405060 folder level ... 2: 020,001 folder, level 3: 020001123456789012 folder ...).
- In the fourth and final level, each folder with its 18 numbers, can only contain folders with the names "**declarante**", "**docs**", "**entidadelegal**", "**proprietario**" and "**representante**".
  May not be the 5 at the same time, but can only be folders with these names.

As you can see in the second folder structure, above, at level 1, I have a wrong folder named "aaa".

- At level 2, I have a wrong folder named "010004a".
- At level 3, I have folders wrong as "010001741014756984a", "010001741z14756984", "0144dshbc" and "014758".

I have a PowerShell script that validates the folder names but how do pa jump folder in folder? How can I do this exercise?

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -notmatch "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+$"
}
```

Comment: Use get-childitem per Level and iterate through each folder level. So, check if first Level contains desired names, than do an foreach gci, and check for second Level requirement and so on. Are we doing your homework? :)

Comment: Of course not intend to do my "homework" but this command "foreach gci" had no knowledge ... Validate already got, but jump folder in folder does not know how to do ... I will test with this command what it does.

Comment: gci is an alias for get-childitem. imeant, you will get all items (directories) of top Level with gci. Than you do an gci in these directories, getting all level 2 directories, which again you test for your naming requirement. If test passes, you will do an gci on these Folders again and so on.

Comment: Yes but my question is how I jump folder in folder ... example, I am in c: \ 01 \ 010001 \ 010001102030405060 validated ok and want to go to c: \ 01 \ 010002 \ 010002102030405061 because the initial 01 folders I have knowledge because they are always 01, 02 ... 13 .... but within each folder are random with no prior knowledge of them.

Comment: `gci C:\ -Directory | % { gci $_.fullname -Directory }` First, gci will give all subdirs of C:\, the %... will give all subdirs of these dirs.

Comment: Or in the other notation `foreach ($dir in gci c:\ -Directory) {gci $dir.fullname -Directory }`.

Comment: This command returns me the contents of each folder, but then what do I do with it? I need "mark" the folders as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the -Recurse switch on Get-ChildItem

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+$" }
```

Comment: I can not use this command in "Recurse" because as I said before, I have several levels and various checks, each in its level. What I look for is how encadiar in each level, the checks I have. In the first case, two numbers in the second case 6 numbers in the third case numbers 18 and in the fourth case show all but the 5 nominees. Checks on each already know how to do, but you can encadiar all? That's what I have doubts ...

Comment: Misunderstood your question. What do you mean by 'encadiar'

Comment: chain, like, plug... Can understand?